# How early before departure can I reserve train tickets in the UK?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, bookings, national-rail

I'm trying to book a train journey in the UK for September. We are currently in April and the National Rail website does not allow me to reserve tickets such a long time (5 months) in advance.

So here is the question: how early can I reserve train tickets in the UK?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of the UK, [the earliest bookable tickets offered by National Rail are Advance Tickets](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/46583.aspx). These are discounted early-bird single journey fares, available in limited numbers and with strict conditions. Advanced tickets are
valid only for the selected journey (although they are changeable prior to departure) and non-refundable.

Turns out that [National Rail has a webpage showing the dates in which Advance Ticket sales open](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/44703.aspx), broken down per subsidiary. This page is automatically updated every day, since **Advance Ticket sales open roughly as early as 12 weeks before departure**.

Note that the train journey will appear in the [Journey Planner](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/), and hence be available for reservation, only after the train timetable has been finalised and published. Moreover [the train timetable is dependent on engineering works](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/44703.aspx). This is to say that the opening of the Advance Ticket sales does not guarantee that a ticket for the journey can be booked.

Comment: 12 weeks = 6 fortnights... I learned that British word recently and I am trying to use it somewhere ;)

Comment: But reserving early doesn't guarantee you a good deal, primarily for bank holidays and other ones.

Comment: Some special features of *advance* tickets: (1) as @JoErNanO says, they are valid only for the specific departure time that you choose at the time of booking. If you miss your train then you will need a new ticket. (2) If you get an e-ticket that you print yourself then you will need a form of identification to verify that you are the person who bought the ticket. (3) If you have one of the orange credit card-sized tickets printed by the train company then the ticket will have two pieces (a ticket and a reservation). You need both for the ticket to be valid.

Comment: The Caledonian Sleeper now allows booking 12 months in advance. https://www.sleeper.scot/

Comment: The Trainline has a really handy Ticket Alert system that will email you when tickets become available (http://www.thetrainline.com/ticketalert/) - don't actually use Trainline to book, because they charge extortionate fees. Also, @Ubiquitous - newer orange tickets have the ticket and the reservation on a single piece. Ticket printing machines are being switched over (Northern Rail ones are mostly done, other operators are being rolled out; machines in ticket offices will be changed last).